# The alignment of my div is different for 2 different divs with the same markup

Tags: html, css

The bottom div is moved further to the left, why is that, how can I align them better?

[Image of how it looks](http://puu.sh/1smgh.png)

[Link to markup](http://pastebin.com/Xv6JFREb)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a terrible question. But it looks like the top `stats` div has a decent amount of padding on it, maybe 50px, and the one below doesnt.

Comment: You need to add code to the question, you can't just say "Heres my website, now fix it". This is not a help forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is because of the Items inside the stats div. The bottom one has more "items" so it is moved further to the left (because it is wider and floated right). To fix this, I would recommend giving that div a fixed width, maybe 400px. so `<div style="float: right; width: 400px;>` on line 30.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it did that :)